# Proof of a different form of Abel's test

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove that the series $\sum a_nb_n$ always converges if

- $\sum a_n(b_n - b_{n+1})$ converges
- {$a_n b_{n+1}$} converges.

I am supposed to use Abel's partial summation:

$\sum_{k=m}^n a_k b_k = \sum_{k=m}^n A_k(b_k - b_{k+1}) - A_{m-1}b_m + A_n b_{n+1}$,

where $A_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k$.

I have tried different ways but none of them seem to get me the right answer. I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Are you sure that the second hypothesis is not "$A_nb_{n+1}$ converges" ?

Comment: Yes. I also have doubts about the hypothesis. This is a problem form Freitag's Complex Analysis and it stays that the sequence {$a_n b_{n+1}$} converges. I even looked for the errata of the book but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true. Take $a_n = 1$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{n}$.

You should replace the $a_n$'s in the hypothesis by $A_n$'s.

Comment: Thank you. I guess it is an error from the book, or it was deliberately written like that to make you think.